# C++ Compilation Error bayesian mixed model

Tags: c++, r, macos-mojave

I am building a bayesian mixed model. When I try to run it, I have a compilation error. I have the latest versions of R, Rstudio and Xcode. Any help would be very appreciated. 
This is my bayesian mixed model

```
model.brm <- brm(prop_coverCoral_transform ~ clogAragonite+cBAAnum+cBAA_yrsSince+cSWHnum+cSWH_yrsSince+clogPARmean+cCoastDev+cOverfish+cMarPoll+cSediment +(1|Region),
  data = mullens, family =  Beta(link = "logit"), prior=c(set_prior('normal(0,10)', class='b')), chain=4, iter=5000, warmup=1000, thin=5)
```

I have this error

```
Compiling the C++ model
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]
In file included from file55c215061c9f.cpp:8:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/StanHeaders/include/src/stan/model/model_header.hpp:4:........it continues
```

it is not clear what it is going wrong.
Thank you

This is the data

```
                   clogAragonite clogPARmean   cBAAnum cBAA_yrsSince    cSWHnum
1        0        0     0.4682656  -0.2576645 0.7493048    -0.1668396 -0.5310235
2        0        0     0.4685222  -0.2741081 0.7493048    -0.1668396 -0.5310235
3        0        0     0.4683210  -0.2485866 0.7493048    -0.1668396 -0.5310235
4        0        0     0.4685777  -0.2658909 0.7493048    -0.1668396 -0.5310235
5        0        0     0.4688343  -0.2822616 0.7493048    -0.1668396 -0.5310235
6        0        0     0.4701175  -0.2864145 0.7493048    -0.1668396 -0.5310235
  cSWH_yrsSince cCoastDev cMarPoll cOverfish cSediment prop_coverCoral
1           NaN         0        0         0         0      0.00249066
2           NaN         0        0         0         0      0.05124341
3           NaN         0        0         0         0      0.13380282
4           NaN         0        0         0         0      0.00666420
5           NaN         0        0         0         0      0.00708801
6           NaN         0        0         0         0    
  prop_coverCoral_transform
1               0.002593921
2               0.051336552
3               0.133878826
4               0.006766594
5               0.007190316
6               0.847241763
```

Comment: Setting up compilers for R on MacOs can be challenging. I have found [this guide](https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/) to be most helpful.

Comment: yes it is very helpful! I solved the problem thank you